# Need to use php foreach to create XML elements and attributes using a second XML

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have an XML doc (`traffic.xml`) that I then used PHP to pull only 2 specific attributes using foreach as there is a ton of them in the original XML to create a PHP(`drivetimeFetch.php`).

What I need to do now is, using `drivetimeFetch.php`, I need to create another xml doc (`carousel_Traffic.xml`) with elements and attributes made up of the 30 or so lines from the stripped `drivetimeFetch.php` I created. Here is where I'm getting stuck. I was able to write the elements and attributes but how do I get each line into its own element block.

Here is what my php looks like:

```
<?php
$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('https://wsidata.weather.com/201303/en-us/55828880/traffic.xml'));
foreach ($xml1->drivetimes->drivetime as $drivetime) {
    echo"<br>";
    echo $drivetime['pathName'].":"." ".$drivetime['driveTimeMinutes']."min \n" ;
}
$xml_txt = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\r\n".'<tickerfeed version="2.4">'."\r\n". 
           '<playlist type="scrolling_carousel" name="TrafficScroll" target="carousel">'."\r\n" ;
$element = '<element>';
$elementClose = '</element>';
$field1 = '<field name="05">';           
$fieldClose = '</field>';
$playlistClose = '</playlist>';
$tickerfeedClose = '</tickerfeed>';

$f = fopen("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\carousel_Traffic.xml", "w"); 
fwrite ($f, $xml_txt. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $element. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $field1. $drivetime['pathName'].":"." ".$drivetime['driveTimeMinutes']."min " . $fieldClose. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $elementClose. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $playlistClose. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $tickerfeedClose. "\r\n" );
fclose ($f);
?>
```

What I need from this is to get that carousel_Traffic.xml to look like is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tickerfeed version="2.4">
<playlist type="scrolling_carousel" name="TrafficScroll" target="carousel">

<element>
<field name="05">I-278: Bklyn Battery Tunnel to Brooklyn Bridge: 10min </field>
</element>
</playlist>
</tickerfeed>
```

For every one of those lines in the `drivetimeFetch.php`, I'm guessing this is a foreach operation but I have no idea how to do that so that the `pathName` and `driveTimeMinutes` for each line gets its own element block. As you can see, I got it to work for only one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) to transform the input XML into your end output. No loop or string concatenation of XML document is needed:

```
// LOAD XML SOURCE
$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('https://wsidata.weather.com/201303/en-us/55828880/traffic.xml'));

// XSLT STRING
$xslstr = '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
             <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes" />
             <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

              <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>

              <xsl:template match="traffic">
                  <tickerfeed version="2.4">
                      <playlist type="scrolling_carousel" name="TrafficScroll" target="carousel">            
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="drivetimes" />
                      </playlist>
                  </tickerfeed>
              </xsl:template>

              <xsl:template match="incidents"/>

              <xsl:template match="drivetimes">
                  <element>
                      <template>Traffic</template>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="drivetime"/>
                  </element>
              </xsl:template>

              <xsl:template match="drivetime">
                  <field name="05"><xsl:value-of select="concat(@pathName, \': \', @driveTimeMinutes, \'min\')"/></field>
              </xsl:template>

           </xsl:stylesheet>';

$xslfile = new SimpleXMLElement($xslstr);

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml1);

// OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\carousel_Traffic.xml', $newXML);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tickerfeed version="2.4">
  <playlist type="scrolling_carousel" name="TrafficScroll" target="carousel">
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">I-95: Bruckner Interchange to I-95 Northbound - Midland Ave/Exit 22: 22min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">Belt Pkwy: Verrazano Brg to Southern State Pkwy E Eastbound - Nassau/Queens County Line: 62min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">I-95 Northbound - Alexander Hamilton Brg to Bruckner Interchange: 14min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">Bronx River Pkwy:  Cross County Pkwy to Bruckner Expressway: 37min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">I-278: Verrazano to Belt Merge: 3min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">Belt Pkwy: Southern State Pkwy to Van Wyck Expwy: 8min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">Belt Pkwy: Ocean Pkwy to Verrazano Brg: 9min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">Verrazano Brg to Brooklyn Brg: 2min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">NYS Thruway: I-287 to Tappan Zee Bridge Tolls: 17min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
      <template>Traffic</template>
      <field name="05">Major Deegan Expwy: Macombs Dam Brg to Third Ave Bridge: 2min</field>
    </element>
    <element>
...
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait!
What I wound up doing was adding the foreach right after the first fwrite ($f, $xml_txt.)

Comment: I updated to fit your actual output. Reconsider this solution or any other that use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) methods (`createElement()`, `appendChild()`, etc.). Do not concatenate strings into XML doc. XML files are not text files.

Comment: Thank you, Parfait. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! After playing around, I figured it out. Here is my working code:

```
<?php
$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('https://wsidata.weather.com/201303/en-us/55828880/traffic.xml'));
foreach ($xml1->drivetimes->drivetime as $drivetime) {
    echo"<br>";
    echo $drivetime['pathName'].":"." ".$drivetime['driveTimeMinutes']."min \n" ;
}
$xml_txt = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\r\n".'<tickerfeed version="2.4">'."\r\n". 
           '<playlist type="scrolling_carousel" name="TrafficScrollIN" target="carousel">'."\r\n" ;
$element = '<element>';
$elementClose = '</element>';
$field1 = '<field name="05">';           
$fieldClose = '</field>';
$playlistClose = '</playlist>';
$tickerfeedClose = '</tickerfeed>';
$template = '<template>';
$templateClose = '</template>';

$f = fopen("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\PIX_Traffic.xml", "w"); 

fwrite ($f, $xml_txt. "\r\n" );
foreach ($xml1->drivetimes->drivetime as $drivetime){
fwrite ($f, $element. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $template. "Traffic" . $templateClose. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $field1. $drivetime['pathName'].":"." ".$drivetime['driveTimeMinutes']."min " . $fieldClose. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $elementClose. "\r\n" );
}
fwrite ($f, $playlistClose. "\r\n" );
fwrite ($f, $tickerfeedClose. "\r\n" );
fclose ($f);
?>
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tickerfeed version="2.4">
<playlist type="scrolling_carousel" name="TrafficScrollIN" target="carousel">

<element>
<template>Traffic</template>
<field name="05">Williamsburg Brg to Long Island Expwy: 11min </field>
</element>
<element>
<template>Traffic</template>
<field name="05">I-278: Bklyn Battery Tunnel to Brooklyn Bridge: 4min </field>
</element>
<element>
<template>Traffic</template>
<field name="05">Major Deegan Expwy: Third Ave Bridge to Major Deegan Expwy Southbound - I-278/Bruckner Expy: 3min </field>
</element>
</playlist>
</tickerfeed>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!